# OKHTTP Unable to resolve host No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

We Published a mobile application and some of our users have trouble to connect to our app. first of all we guess it was a dns Issue so we change our DNS from Digital ocean to Cloudflare but it didn't fix anything.
on Android Devices we use Retrofit 2.4 to connect to our server. but some of our users cannot connect to server but they have ping on server and can open website in their browser but they can connect only with vpn.

We got this Exception from firebase, we use `Retrofit 2.4.0` and `OKHTTP 3.10.0`. There is nothing in their issues on github or on the net.

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException
Unable to resolve host "jomlex.com": No address associated with hostname
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName (Inet6AddressImpl.java:125)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName (InetAddress.java:752)
okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup (Dns.java:40)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy (RouteSelector.java:149)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next (RouteSelector.java:84)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection (StreamAllocation.java:214)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection (StreamAllocation.java:135)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream (StreamAllocation.java:114)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:200)
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute (RealCall.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java:32)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
Caused by android.system.GaiException
android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo (Posix.java)
libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo (ForwardingOs.java:55)
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName (Inet6AddressImpl.java:106)
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr (Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName (InetAddress.java:752)
okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup (Dns.java:40)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress (RouteSelector.java:185)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy (RouteSelector.java:149)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next (RouteSelector.java:84)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection (StreamAllocation.java:214)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection (StreamAllocation.java:135)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream (StreamAllocation.java:114)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:200)
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute (RealCall.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java:32)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Seems to me as a Internet Connection problem rather than coding problem

Comment: The general reason for this issue is permission in most of the cases. Do you add Internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: @JonasLochmann I don't think so when they tried to connect, they were in support chat and I'm sure they had Internet Connection.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt Yes I said some of our users cannot connect but they can connect with vpn, they throw this exception, I think something wrong with dns in OKHTTP.

Comment: @HoseinIT How did you fix that? some of our user can connect with VPN it's weird !

Comment: Can't be solved if it's a network issue @Siyanew

Comment: Have you solved an issue?

Comment: @user3489820 Yes I bought a new static IP for my server because that previous IP was banned in some ISPs.